Employer changing resignation date to avoid holiday day pay
I work at at private expensive preschool for over a year now. On November 6, 2024, I sent my resignation nation letter to the school owners. Also they are HR and school director.
I planned on working until the end of the year. My last day is January 2, 2025, they then wrote back via email telling me last day would be December 20, 2024. They are doing this to avoid giving me holiday pay. I work 8-5 Monday through Friday, my job is physically stressful and my coworker is pregnant and unable to help with our students, picking them up etc. they are 1 and under not yet walking.
Is this legal or ethical?
I say all this because I work very hard and have been a good employee.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Yes, in the US this is legal unless you have a contract or union, and those represent a diminishingly small part of the workforce. It’s not ethical, but  that unfortunately doesn’t help you in any way. Welcome to peak capitalism.
But you have a little bit of power here. If they say “we want to move up your resignation date,” refuse in writing to this negotiation and keep a copy, and say they’ll need to terminate you to get an earlier end date. While they can do this according to US at-will employment laws, it means you are eligible to apply for unemployment and may make them nervous about lawsuits especially if you are part of a protected class.  Maybe they’ll relent and leave your last day end of year; at least you will have unemployment coverage if your new job falls through and will have “said out loud” you don’t want to be treated that way.  Not awesome but it’s your best outcome.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

It would be a good idea to have this looked over by a lawyer. Make sure you don't sign anything before that.
You have resigned effective Jan 2nd. Your employer has unilaterally changed your last day to Dec 20. Depending on your contract and your local law this could be considered a breach of good faith and/or it can be interpreted as change from a resignation to a termination.
A termination may entitle you to some severance or unemployment benefits and there may be other significant differences,
Your first response should be that you do not accept that new resignation date and that, as far as you are concerned, your last day of work is Jan 2. If you have the stomach (and the resources) for it you can try to play hard ball: You can tell them that Dec 20 is not acceptable and the only choice of resignation dates you are willing to consider are either Jan 2 or tomorrow. Leaving with short or no notice, is likely to put them into a serious bind you may be able to leverage this (at the risk of being fired).
But again, a local lawyer is your best adviser here.

Shame on me for giving the advance notice.

That's a frustrating and painful lesson to learn. You were trying to be nice and they retaliated. Well, soon enough you will be out of there. In general it's better to assume the worst and play it safe. For many companies that have a bonus program that pays out at a specific date, the day after is the day with the highest amount of resignations. Most people wait until they have the check in safely their pockets.

I don't think a lawyer will cost less than those few days are worth

@DonQuiKong Are lawyers that expensive your side of the pond? I would hope that those two weeks' worth of pay at an "expensive preschool" (thus hopefully somewhat well-paid) should be enough to cover an initial consultation with a lawyer (speaking from an EU perspective where lawyers charge a few hundred € per hour).

@TooTea fair, I was including the expected net result of that consultation vs. just sending a letter yourself. Just knowing that there may be a chance to fight it doesn't help you much. Either it's a clear cut case (which you would probably get as an answer here) or the information doesn't provide much chance of conversion into money.

@DonQuiKong In many jurisdictions, there are some free resources available for employees, which, while they often won't give actual legal advice, may provide some assistance. Some provide substantially more assistance for free. It's also routine for lawyers to give at least a little time (e.g., 30 minutes to an hour) of free consultation as part of the lawyer trying to get the person as a client (i.e., get to know you; how the lawyer sees case proceeding; what actions they would take). How beneficial that would be is unclear, but it would only cost the OP time for the free consultation(s).

You wanted to make sure you got your holiday pay. That is understandable. If you can pick the last day of work then making it in early January makes sense.
The company would prefer that the last day be just before the holiday pay. That is understandable.
If both sides have flexibility to set the last day, then always assume the other side will pick what is best for them or worst for you.

Is this legal or ethical?

Unless it violates labor laws or the specific policies or contract, then it is ethical. Remember you used the same logic to set your last day of work. Your mistake was telling them before you had to.
Just as you need to understand all the impacts on leaving a company: PTO, Holiday pay, insurance coverage etc. The company has to understand what happens if they move the date earlier.
Yes it can make you unhappy, and you will feel betrayed. They also have to understand if this changes it from a resignation to a termination.
We get questions on this site regarding picking the day to tell the company. Some wonder how to factor in vacation days and business trips.  others want to get the holiday or annual bonus. Your situation is similar. Notify them after the money hits the bank, not before.
Unfortunately by telling them now, they know you will not be around a long time. Even if you say fine, I won't resign, they know you will once January arrives.
Regarding labor laws and your contract, you need expert advice.

“Unless it violates labor laws or the specific policies or contract, then it is ethical.” — Really?  You don’t think labor laws ever have shortfalls that leave some unethical behaviour legal?

@PLL the next sentences say "Remember you used the same logic to set your last day of work. Your mistake was telling them before you had to"  You picked a day to maximize your income, they picked one to minimize their costs.

@mhoran_psprep sure, but they also gave the preschool significant advanced notice to avoid putting them in a tight spot with one employee curently unable to fulfill all their duties. Then the school respondend by taking advantage of the OP's generosity at the OP's expense. Maybe that doesn't make it unethical, but the situation is not entirely symmetric, at least.

Realistically I don't think we have anywhere enough info to tell whether this is or isn't ethical. This depends very much on the actual relationship of the employee and employer, the way this was communicated and what the expectations were. In this particular case I'd tend to side with the employee, but it is very hard to judge unless you know the specifics. We don't know what the costs for the employer are or how the resignation was timed/termed. In EU I tend to side with employers since they usually have a much much worse position than employees, the US is much more employer friendly.

Things can definitely be unethical while still being strictly legal. Also, you're making the assumption that OP picked the last day they did specifically to get the holiday pay, but it's also entirely possible that they simply picked the last day of the current "semester" (which for schools in US commonly falls within a week of New Years Day).

Ultimately you may have to check with a lawyer instead of random internet people. Possibily a state agency might be helpful, but they won't give you a clear answer either.
We can't know for sure.
The answer is "it depends". If you have a contact that spells out termination, then check that.
If you are in an "At Will" employment situation, which is most likely, then they can do this.

If you had to give four weeks notice and give six weeks (to take advantage of bank holidays), they can give you four weeks notice. They can’t change your notice, but they can lay you off independently. If it takes the employer two weeks to figure this out, you are safe. If you had given notice two weeks later, you would have been safe.

@gnasher729 Not necessarily. Just because OP has to give four weeks notice (assuming they do) doesn't mean the employer has to. I would even hazard a guess that the school could've let OP go the day they handed in their notice if they really wanted to. The crucial distinction though is that if the school decides to let OP go before their resignation date, then it's now a termination, not a resignation, and OP is now entitled to any contractual termination benefits and unemployment payments, or even a wrongful termination suit if it's warranted (which here it probably isn't, but still).
